# How to Disable Auto Silence

Tags: audio, silent-mode, mute

My Motorola Electrify M keeps auto-silencing the ringer.  How do I disable auto-silece?  My phone is running Android version 4.1.2.

It seems to go on silent when I have meetings scheduled.  It wouldn't be so bad, except that it never re-activates the ringer, so I keep missing calls!  Any thoughts on how to disable the auto-ring silencer would be great.  If it makes a difference, I'm also using the calendar app aCalendar.

Comment: @JimFell I've taken the liberty of adding that information to your question. You can [edit] it if you have any more to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Motorola Electrify M comes with a set of functions called Smart Actions, which can be deployed. A sample from their User Guide is the silencing of the ringer when inside meetings. See the User Guide [here](http://www.uscellular.com/uscellular/pdf/motorola-electrify-m-user-manual.pdf) to find help in refining the criteria triggers, so that the ringer is restored. Look for \Control and Customize\Smart Actions\Help.
Like most trigger-based actions, each comes with some downside, so either some refinement, or complete disabling will solve your difficulty.